# Chrome downloads the reloaded page on HTTP 205 response after an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, http-status-codes

Working on a project, I just make an AJAX request to process some datas.
The server, once the job is done, returns a `HTTP 205 RESET CONTENT` response

I use this status code to tell the requester to [reset the document view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#205)

Here is the piece of code I use

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/unread',
    method: 'PUT',
    data: {
        notifications: elements
    }
}).done(function(content, message, xhr) {
    if (205 !== xhr.status) {
        // Generic error message
        return;
    }

    window.location.reload(true)
}).fail(function() {
    // Generic error message
})
```

This works fine on Internet Explorer *(8 and upwards)*, Firefox *(28.0)* and Opera *(12.16)*. However Chrome *(33.0)* and Opera *(20.0)* instead of refreshing the page, **downloads** the response content **of the page being reloaded**<sup>[*dump*](http://pastebin.com/D0WdQfUx)</sup> when calling `window.location.reload`

Here's what I've tried

- `window.location.href = window.location.href` gives the same result
- `history.go(0)` gives the same result
- If I remove the `window.location.reload`, nothing gets reloaded
- Clearing the cache, removing the local state or going in private navigation doesn't change anything
- If I change the response code (e.g 204), it works fine

Here is the visual network of what's happening

[image: Chrome makes a download]

Additionnal informations (and deeper investigations)

- I'm on Ubuntu 12.04
- Error could be reproduced on a different computer with Windows 7 (Same chrome version)
- Error couldn't be reproduced on a different computer with Debian 7.1 (Same chrome version)

Why does Chrome and Opera behave like this on a `205` HTTP response?

Comment: Since AJAX requests are made in the _background_, you can not expect the same reaction to certain HTTP response codes as you maybe could when they were received in answer to a _direct_ request by the browser … the same is true f.e. for 301/302/Location redirects.

Comment: That's why I'm wondering why it's behaving like this. The AJAX response status code shouldn't matter for such a case. But it does, and only in chrome.

Comment: Maybe I did not understand you correctly … so what exactly does Chrome “download” in that case?

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear. It downloads the *reloaded page* as dumped [here](http://pastebin.com/D0WdQfUx) (not the request with a 205 response code)

Comment: Could you tell what is the content of `xhr.status` ? is it a string ? like '205' ?

Comment: No, this is an integer. This is just a check which pass. Removing the test doesn't change anything.

Comment: Have you tried `history.go(0)`?

Comment: Same happens with `history.go(0)`

Comment: @Touki Did you tried to delete cache of Chrome? Also you can delete the `Local State` file in `ToukiUser/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data`.

Comment: Clearing the cache, removing the local state or going in private navigation doesn't change anything

Answer (score 3):

The closest I could find was that it might be a bug, because in this file:
   https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/chromium/+/trunk/net/http/http_stream_parser.cc

the comment starting at line 837 does not match the code at line 850: i.e. the comment doesn't mention that a 205 must be of zero length, but the code treats 205 like 1xx, 204, and 304. That was actually the only blink code I could find that mentioned 205 (outside of defining constants).

It might also be worth trying the latest Opera version; if the problem also happens there, it points the finger more strongly at a bug in the Blink source code.

Comment: I'm starting to think of a bug too, but I don't see anything that could be relevant to the problem in the link you gave. Just tried with Opera 12.16, the sample works fine

Comment: I think you need at least Opera 15 to be using blink; I guess you are on Linux?

Comment: You are right! I tested in Opera 20 (for windows, since it's not available for Linux) and the same problem happens

Comment: Despite this doesn't answer to the question, this is the closest (and only) answer available. Therefore, I'll award the bounty to you but leave the question as unanswered.